# server closed the stream without sending trailers

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, envoyproxy

I’m trying o communicate from Envoy to Envoy using gRPC for Kubernetes(Amazon EKS).

I have an envoy in my sidecar and I am using grpcurl to validate the request.
The request is delivered to the application container and there are no errors, but the console returns the following results

```
server closed the stream without sending trailers
```

I don’t know what the reason for the above problem is, and what could be the reason for this result??
I was able to confirm that the response came back fine when I hit a single service before connecting with envoy.

this my envoy config

```
    admin:
      access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 127.0.0.1
          port_value: 10000
    static_resources:
      listeners:
        - name: listener_secure_grpc
          address:
            socket_address:
              protocol: TCP
              address: 0.0.0.0
              port_value: 8443
          traffic_direction: INBOUND
          filter_chains:
            - filters:
                - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
                    codec_type: auto
                    stat_prefix: ingress_http
                    route_config:
                      name: local_route
                      virtual_hosts:
                        - name: service_grpc
                          domains:
                            - "*"
                          routes:
                            - match:
                                prefix: "/"
                              route:
                                cluster: cluster_grpc
                                max_stream_duration:
                                  grpc_timeout_header_max: 30s
                    tracing: {}
                    http_filters:
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.health_check
                        typed_config:
                          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.health_check.v3.HealthCheck"
                          pass_through_mode: false
                          headers:
                          - name: ":path"
                            exact_match: "/healthz"
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.router
              transport_socket:
                name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
                typed_config:
                  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext"
                  common_tls_context:
                    tls_certificates:
                      - certificate_chain:
                          filename: /etc/ssl/grpc/tls.crt
                        private_key:
                          filename: /etc/ssl/grpc/tls.key
        - name: listener_stats
          address:
            socket_address:
              protocol: TCP
              address: 0.0.0.0
              port_value: 10001
          traffic_direction: INBOUND
          filter_chains:
            - filters:
                - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
                    codec_type: AUTO
                    stat_prefix: ingress_http
                    route_config:
                      virtual_hosts:
                        - name: backend
                          domains:
                            - "*"
                          routes:
                            - match:
                                prefix: /stats
                              route:
                                cluster: cluster_admin
                    http_filters:
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.router
        - name: listener_healthcheck
          address:
            socket_address:
              protocol: TCP
              address: 0.0.0.0
              port_value: 10010
          traffic_direction: INBOUND
          filter_chains:
            - filters:
                - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
                    codec_type: AUTO
                    stat_prefix: ingress_http
                    route_config: {}
                    http_filters:
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.health_check
                        typed_config:
                          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.health_check.v3.HealthCheck"
                          pass_through_mode: false
                          headers:
                          - name: ":path"
                            exact_match: "/healthz"
                      - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      clusters:
        - name: cluster_grpc
          connect_timeout: 1s
          type: STATIC
          http2_protocol_options: {}
          upstream_connection_options:
            tcp_keepalive: {}
          load_assignment:
            cluster_name: cluster_grpc
            endpoints:
              - lb_endpoints:
                - endpoint:
                    address:
                      socket_address:
                        address: 127.0.0.1
                        port_value: 1443
        - name: cluster_admin
          connect_timeout: 1s
          type: STATIC
          load_assignment:
            cluster_name: cluster_grpc
            endpoints:
              - lb_endpoints:
                - endpoint:
                    address:
                      socket_address:
                        address: 127.0.0.1
                        port_value: 10000
```

P.S 2021.03.19

Here's what else I found out.
When I request from the ingress host, I get the above failure, but when I request from the service, I get a normal response!

Comment: Can you provide more details about your setup and config files ?

Comment: Sorry, I added the envoy config.

Comment: Are you using specific tutorial for setup ?